# Is there a way to access the classification of photos done by Google Photos? Or recently viewed photos?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, google-photos

Question pretty much says it.
I want to know if Google exposes the classification of photos on a user's phone through some API - so that I wouldn't have to implement a system to analyze and classify photos for my app.

I also need a way to access recently viewed photos.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the Google Photos Library API: http://developers.google.com/photos

Once a user has authorized your app, you can [access the library](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list) and [filter media items by content category](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/apply-filters). For example, you could find photos that contain animals, landmarks or are of receipts.

Unfortunately there's no option in this API to find labels that have been assigned to a particular image or video.

If you would like to classify your own images that are not part of Google Photos, you could use the [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) to detect labels and other image attributes.

If you are after an on-device option, you could also take a look at [Tensorflow Mobile](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/mobile_intro) and [Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/) and use a [prepared image labeling model](https://medium.com/tensorflow/using-tensorflow-lite-on-android-9bbc9cb7d69d).